# Why simultaneous use of multiple swap space rather than sequentially, in accordance with the priority?

Tags: swap

Two allocated swap space, the first /dev/hda6 hdd on a separate partition, connected via fstab, priority is assigned -1. Second is created in RAM using systemd in the form of /dev/zram0 c priority 32767. The swapon output indicates that the kernel sees both swap. As I understand it, the system first needs to use a swap partition with higher priority (on/dev/zram0) and then with lower (/dev/sda6).
But according to information from swapon, system under load uses **both** swap, about 50/50. When the load is removed, freed swap both is also roughly proportional to. Why?
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of textual output, paste the *actual text*...